# Не устанавливается расширение для PHP7 через pecl

Tags: php, php7, memcached, pecl

Устанавливаю memcached через **sudo pecl install memcached**
Выводит ошибку:

`MBP-Artem:~ artemerbulatov$ sudo pecl install memcached
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
pecl/memcached can optionally use PHP extension "igbinary" (version >= 2.0)
pecl/memcached can optionally use PHP extension "msgpack" (version >= 2.0)
downloading memcached-3.1.3.tgz ...
Starting to download memcached-3.1.3.tgz (82,673 bytes)
....................done: 82,673 bytes
15 source files, building
running: phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
libmemcached directory [no] : 
zlib directory [no] : 
use system fastlz [no] : 
enable igbinary serializer [no] : 
enable msgpack serializer [no] : 
enable json serializer [no] : 
enable server protocol [no] : 
enable sasl [yes] : 
enable sessions [yes] : 
building in /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootTNWOax/memcached-3.1.3
running: /private/tmp/pear/install/memcached/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-libmemcached-dir=no --with-zlib-dir=no --with-system-fastlz=no --enable-memcached-igbinary=no --enable-memcached-msgpack=no --enable-memcached-json=no --enable-memcached-protocol=no --enable-memcached-sasl=yes --enable-memcached-session=yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable memcached support... yes, shared
checking for libmemcached... yes, shared
checking whether to enable memcached session handler support... yes
checking whether to enable memcached igbinary serializer support... no
checking whether to enable memcached json serializer support... no
checking whether to enable memcached msgpack serializer support... no
checking whether to enable memcached sasl support... yes
checking whether to enable memcached protocol support... no
checking whether to use system FastLZ library... no
checking for ZLIB... yes, shared
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking for zlib location... /usr/local/opt/zlib
checking for session includes... configure: error: Cannot find php_session.h
ERROR:`/private/tmp/pear/install/memcached/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-libmemcached-dir=no --with-zlib-dir=no --with-system-fastlz=no --enable-memcached-igbinary=no --enable-memcached-msgpack=no --enable-memcached-json=no --enable-memcached-protocol=no --enable-memcached-sasl=yes --enable-memcached-session=yes' failed
`

Что пошло не так? старая версия PECL?

Comment: У вас установлен пакет libmemcached-dev

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов Но как подключить и работать с расширением? в php -m его нет

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов файла memcached.so тоже нигде нет

Comment: Если судить по ошибке, то не может найти файл php_session.h ( у меня он лежит в /usr/include/php/20170718/ext/session). Какая версия PHP используется?

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов PHP 7.1.23

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов Поиск mdfind php_session.h -name показал:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/php/ext/session/php_session.h
/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.21/include/php/ext/session/php_session.h

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601476/how-to-install-memcached-module-for-php7-1-on-macos-high-sierra

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, зачем вы откатываете правки к вопросу? Они явно улучшали внешний вид, вы же упорно возвращаете исходный вид.

Comment: @AK Так ведь наоборот, мой вариант соответствует выводу из консоли со всеми переводами строк. А при ваших правках всё вывелось в одну линию...

Comment: А,  понял куда смотреть. Да, определённо этот фрагмент лучше выглядит, оставим так.